# How to improve performance on SUM from float values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a query (on MySQL 5.7) that takes about 1s to execute on 3M rows. The desired result is a SUM of float values per day within the last 30days:

Query:

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    SUM(RIX) as value
FROM
    tbl1 v
JOIN tbl2 b ON v.BRAND_ID = b.ID and  b.MANUFACTURER_ID = 18670
WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1613663944) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1616255944)
     AND type = 'kwd'
group by v.DATE
```

Tbl1 (10K rows):

```
create table tbl1
    (
        ID              mediumint unsigned auto_increment
            primary key,
        ID_parent       mediumint unsigned null,
        MANUFACTURER_ID mediumint unsigned not null,
        BRAND           varchar(255)       null,
        CREATED         date               null,
        constraint test
            unique (MANUFACTURER_ID, BRAND),
    );
    
    create index idx2
        on tbl1 (ID_parent);
    
    create index idx3
        on tbl1 (MANUFACTURER_ID);
    
    create index idx4
        on tbl1 (BRAND);
```

Tbl2 (3M rows:

```
create table tbl2
(
    DATE        date                       not null,
    MERCHANT_ID mediumint unsigned         not null,
    TYPE        enum ('cat', 'kwd', 'css') not null, 
    BRAND_ID    mediumint unsigned         not null,
    RIX         float unsigned             not null,
    primary key (DATE, TYPE, MERCHANT_ID, BRAND_ID)
)


create index idx1
    on tbl2 (RIX);
```

I could not get it to perform faster. Any ideas on how to improve the query time?

Comment: add a composite index on `type` and `date`

Comment: Look at 3M rows in 1s?  That's fast.  Computers are not infinitely fast!

Answer (score 0):

```
primary key (DATE, TYPE, MERCHANT_ID, BRAND_ID)
```

Try rearranging it to

```
primary key (TYPE, DATE, MERCHANT_ID, BRAND_ID)
```

That would make this more efficient:

```
WHERE type = ...
  AND date BETWEEN ...
```

`tbl1` has an index starting with `MANUFACTURER_ID`; don't add another index on just `MANUFACTURER_ID`.

(Please qualify each column with the table alias, it is hard to read the query.  While you are at it, fix `v.BRAND_ID` and others!!)